# How to give WIDGET 2 the same which is given to WIDGET 1, (Widget 1 build Widget 2)

Tags: flutter

I want to pass Car123 to "Card Image Section" but having a null error
like i pass the Car class to buyild CarSearchCard Widget and it inturns build the CardInfoSection which takes the same args how can i do that???

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ghostprotocols/models/car_model.dart';
import 'package:responsive_screen_utils/responsive_screen_size_extension.dart';

// Container Widget
class CarSearchCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const CarSearchCard({super.key, required this.car123});

  final CarModel car123;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 133.0.w,
      // container DECOR
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
            spreadRadius: 2,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: const Offset(0, 0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: const Row(
        children: [
          CardImageSection(),
          CardInfoSection(
            car: car123,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Card Image Section
class CardImageSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardImageSection({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 2,
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 152.0.w,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary),
          child:
              // IMAGE STACK
              Stack(
            children: [
              // BG IMAGE FOR LOADING
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/skull.png',
                  width: 100.0.w,
                  height: 100.0.w,
                ),
              ),
              // Feature Image Container
              SizedBox(
                height: 152.0.w,
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://ghostprotocols.pk/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/IMG-20230723-WA0170-q9u95wz1g3p6t8ho5ou8vdhp8c5q6mm6xbisz6vq5c.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              // Image count Container
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child:
                    // Image Count
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 25.0.h,
                        width: 43.0.w,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5, vertical: 1),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                        child:
                            // Main Image Count Row
                            Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.camera_alt,
                              size: 13.0.w,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            // Image Count Number
                            Text('1',
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .bodyLarge
                                    ?.copyWith(fontSize: 14.0.sp))
                          ],
                        )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardInfoSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardInfoSection({super.key, required this.car});
  final CarModel car;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 3,
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      child:
          // main info container
          Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // make
            Text(
              '',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodySmall
                  ?.copyWith(fontSize: 14.0.sp),
            ),
            // model - varient
            Text(
              'Civic Oriel i-VTEC 1.8 CVT',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodyMedium
                  ?.copyWith(fontSize: 16.0.sp),
            ),
            // demand
            Text(
              'PKR 52.00 lacs',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium?.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 18.0.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            // City
            Text(
              'Islamabad',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodySmall
                  ?.copyWith(fontSize: 13.0.sp),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 2,
            ),
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // year
                  Text(
                    '2018',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodySmall
                        ?.copyWith(fontSize: 13.0.sp),
                  ),
                  VerticalDivider(
                    width: 15,
                    indent: 4,
                    thickness: 1,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    // color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  // Mileage
                  Text(
                    '58,000 km',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodySmall
                        ?.copyWith(fontSize: 13.0.sp),
                  ),
                  VerticalDivider(
                    width: 15,
                    thickness: 1,
                    indent: 4,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    // color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  // Engine
                  Text(
                    'Petrol',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodySmall
                        ?.copyWith(fontSize: 13.0.sp),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can create a new var but it will also be null initailly please help me with this.

What can i do to pass these args to the next widget from the 1st one??

Comment: If you want to use one arg to another or a lot of widgets, you can use from state management like(GetX, bloc and provider)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you declared the Row to be const. But it is not const because there is a non-const variable (card123) within it.  When you get the error message about "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter..." try removing the previous "const".